# My custom UIView not being displayed on screen

Tags: ios, uiview, customization, uipickerview

I created a custom UIView to hold a picker view and a nav bar with a couple of buttons. I also created a custom nib with the nav bar, 2 buttons and the picker, all of which are linked to my header file. I made it a delegate for each individual class to handle all of the picker view delegates. My problem is that it wont display on screen when needed. I know the method gets called but the custom view wont appear. Below is my code.

CustomPicker.m:

```
- (IBAction)selectClick:(id)sender
{
    NSObject *obj = [self.list objectAtIndex:[self.picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    [self.delegate pickerDidSelect:obj];
}

- (IBAction)selectCancel:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate removePickerFromView:self];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(320, 260);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }

    self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    self.picker.dataSource = self;
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    return self;
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return [self.delegate numberOfComponentsInPicker:pickerView];
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.delegate picker:pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:component];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.delegate picker:pickerView titleForRow:row forComponent:component];
}
```

Method called to display

```
-(void)displayPicker
{
    NSLog(@"display picker");
    picker = [[CustomPicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, 320, 260)];
#warning picker set up incomplete
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
    CGRect frame = picker.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 260);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
        [picker setFrame:frame];
    }];
}
```

Now, I just dont get why my custom view isnt being displayed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of your `CustomPicker` class does not add any subviews to itself. Your custom picker view is properly being added and displayed but it is empty so there is nothing to see.

Update the `initWithFrame:` method of `CustomPicker` to add `self.picker` to `self`.

```
[self addSubview:self.picker];
```

BTW - your code to create and setup the `UIPickerView` should be done inside the `if` statement. You don't want to run that code if `self` is `nil`.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(320, 260);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
        self.picker.dataSource = self;
        self.picker.delegate = self;
        self.picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        [self addSubview:self.picker];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Well i created a nib file, sorry i should have mentioned that. The nib file is a UIView with the navbar, 2 buttons and the picker. The nav bar and picker are linked to a property and the 2 buttons are connected to the 2 methods

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the code you posted is doing everything in code. You make no attempt to create a view from a nib. Make the change I suggested and the picker will appear.

Comment: Ok so you were right, i made those changes and it worked. Now how do i get it to load from my nib?

Comment: I have no idea how to load from your nib. I do everything in code.